# Webpack is adding extra code to bundled file (resulting it to throw error after include)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am setting bundling in my node project with webpack. I have created webpack config file to bundle file. but after including bundle file I got an error.

I am trying to bundle jquery file into output path. I am able to bundle It using below webpack.config.js code.

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
        target: 'web',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/javascripts"),
            filename: "bundle-jquery.js",
        },
        entry: './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    }
```

Now I am including output path which is bundled into script src replacing jquery. But its not working and I am getting "$ not defined error". By viewing bundled file, I found that there is an extra code added at start into bundled file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it completely wrong. If you want jquery in your project, you should import it in your code.

Entry should be your `main.js` or whatever your entry file is called. Then in `main.js` do:

```
import $ from 'jquery' // or use relative path
```

Webpack will then bundle jquery for you.